# C++ floating point comparison

Tags: c++, floating-point

Suppose you have have a rectangle, bottom-left point 0,0 and upper-right point is 100,100. 
Now two line intersects the rectangle. I have to find out the coordinate of the intersection point. I have done that. Now the problem is I can't tell whether it is inside the rectangle or not. I used double comparison. But I think it is giving me wrong answer. Suppose the intersection point is ( x , y ). I used this checking for comparison : if( x >= 0.0 && x <= 100.0 &&  y >= 0.0 && y <= 100.0 ). What should I do?

```
//this function generates line
line genline( int x1 , int y1 , int x2 , int y2 ){
    line l ;
    l.A = y2 - y1 ;
    l.B = x1 - x2 ;
    l.C = l.A * x1 + l.B * y1 ;
    return l ;
}
//this function checks intersection
bool intersect( line m ,line n ) {
    int det = m.A * n.B - m.B * n.A ;
    if( det == 0 ){
        return false ;
    }
    else {
        double x = ( n.B * m.C - m.B * n.C ) / ( det * 1.0 ) ;
        double y = ( m.A * n.C - n.A * m.C ) / ( det * 1.0 ) ;        
        if( x >= 0.0 && x <= L && y >= 0.0 && y <= W ) { return true ; }
        else{ return false ; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Both the line are stretched to infinity.

Comment: Are you sure your intersection point calculation is correct? Can we see some more code?

Comment: Your rectangle test is fine. Please describe why you think it fails. Please give an example x,y value for which your test fails and you feel it should not.

Comment: "But I think it is giving me wrong answer" is not good enough. You need to describe exactly how it fails in your eyes. It's no good making us guess.

Comment: Please give an example x,y value for which your test fails and you feel it should not.

Comment: It's a part of a algorithmic problem. I'm getting wrong answer. So I thought it's maybe because of floating point calculation. I don't know in what case my program fails. User's are not allowed to see test cases :(

Comment: @keith should it be a problem? I havn't done any division before it.

Comment: @caso One of the main things about algorithm competitions is that you're meant to be able to think up *your own* test cases.

Comment: @quasiverse I know. But in this case I can't figure it out.

Comment: Take it one step at a time. Break your algorithm into small pieces and test those pieces individually. This is known as unit testing.

Comment: Did you mean that the two lines intersect **each other**, not the rectangle?

Comment: I am doing that right now. I just want to make sure that this particular part won't give me problems.

Comment: @Ben both the line goes through the rectangle and the intersection point of them...

Comment: @caso: The intersection with the rectangle is always on the edge of the rectangle.  On the other hand, testing whether the point where the two lines intersect, is inside the rectangle or not, could be useful.

Comment: @caso. Seems fine to me. If this is your actual code, I'd check that `L`, `W` are really what you think they are. Global single letter variables might have some sort of name conflict. Failing that, you need to identify the cases that might be failing. With this kind of simple mathematical function, writing two completely different implementations and generating a massive set of random test cases to cross validate is often useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your math looks like it's right. By the way, If a line intersects something, it is always inside that something.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: what happens if the y of intersection point is 99.999999... will the compiler round it up?

Comment: @caso It depends on the floating point math, the compiler wont necessarily round it up, it will try to store it as accurately as it can in a float or a double. Doubles give more precision than floats.

Comment: @caso You are being paranoid. Are you aware that floating point arithmetic has finite precision?

Comment: @quasiverse  OP -  "But I think it is giving me wrong answer" Me - "Your math looks like it's right."

Comment: @MMavipc Yes. The maths looks alright and therefore it isn't what is causing the problem.

Comment: This answer is correct.  The algorithm can be simplified to `bool IsIntersectionInsideRectangle(Rectangle, IntersectionPoint) { return true; }`

Answer (score 0):

Checking to see if a point is inside a rectangle is relatively easy. However, the challenge is to find the intersection between two line segments. There are a large number of corner cases to that problem and limited accuracy of floating point numbers play a huge roll here.

Your algorithm seems to be overly simplistic. For a deeper discussion about this topic you can look at [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/08/29/intersecting-lines/) and [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/09/08/intersecting-lines-part-2/). This two parts article investigates the problem of finding the intersection of two lines using floating point numbers. Notice that they are about MATLAB not C++ though that does not change the problem and the algorithms are easily translatable to any language.

Depending on application, even with clever tricks floating point representation might not simply cut it for some geometry problems. [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/index.html) is a C++ library dedicated to computational geometry that deals with these kind problems. When necessary it uses arbitrary precision arithmetic to handle degenerate cases.

Comment: Just because it seems simplistic doesn't mean it's incorrect: http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=geometry2

Comment: @quasiverse I included two links to a blog that discusses this issue in details. A quick look shows that the OP's algorithm does not consider a lot of cases. It is basically translation of the maths to code without considering numerical issues of floating-point representation. So yes, I do see a problem with that. The link you provide, unfortunately, does not deal the problem cases and is incomplete.

Comment: Looking at the links, half of it seems to be pictures and quite a bit of the code seems to be `plot(stuff)` but that's besides the point. The point is that the code *is* correct and more generally that things don't have to be complicated to be correct.

Comment: @quasiverse No the code is not correct. For example it fails in the case of a horizontal line segment intersecting a vertical line segment. The "det" will be always zero and it will report no intersection. This is a simple case and is not even a floating-point related problems.

Comment: I believe you are incorrect. Could you provide an example of a vertical and horizontal line for which it incorrectly does not identify an intersection?

Comment: @quasiverse yes, you are right. I read it wrong and it works for the example I had in mind. Still, the code does not check to see if the calculated intersection point is actually on both line segments. For example consider a line1 between (0,0)-(3,3) and line2 between (0,9)-(9,0). The code decides that the two segments intersect at (4.5,4.5) while this point is not on line1.

Comment: If you read the text after the code you would see it checks for that.

Comment: @quasiverse This discussion is not really relevant to my point. My point was a floating-point algorithm to find if two lines intersect or not and if yes, reporting the intersection point is not trivial. You seem to disagree and say that the code, as is, is complete.

Comment: @quasiverse My example shows otherwise. Having said that, I read the post again and fail to see how it covers this problem "in text". The only condition that the text adds seem to be that we know the lines intersect the rectangle but does not say what happens if one end point of one line is inside the rectangle. My example above is one of such cases (in this case other end points are on the rectangle but they do not affect our discussion). In this example the code fails. So I'm curious, why this example is already covered by the code/text?

Comment: It says in the text: "[...] you need to make sure that the point you found is on both of the line segments." and then goes on to say the method (which is quite trivial) to do that.

Comment: Ah you are talking about your link not the question here! Yes I saw that too but it does not go into the details of how to do it. As a result the code he presented is not complete and should not be used directly. Anyway, it seems we both agree that an algorithm to find the intersection of two line segments is more complex than 7 lines.

Comment: @AlefSin One thing I didn't clear is that the lines are stretched to infinity. For this reason my code will work. But I was confused with the intersection point being inside the rectangle.

Comment: @caso I see. I guess a question that others also asked is why "you think it is giving your wrong answer"? The if statement you have there to check if a point is inside a rectangle is fine so problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

When you're dealing with floating point (or double), testing for equality is naïve and will fail in edge cases. Every comparison you make should be in reference to "epsilon", an extremely small quantity that doesn't matter. If two numbers are within epsilon for each other, then they are considered equal.

For example, instead of "if(a == b)", you need:

```
bool isEqual(double a, double b, double epsilon = 1.E-10)
{    return fabs(a - b) <= epsilon;
}
```

Pick a suitable value for epsilon depending on your problem domain.